# what is the usage of instantaneous fair share in FairSchduler?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

In fair Scheduler,we take the instantaneous fair share as a very important value,but I didn't see the usage about the sorting the jobs except in the preemtion or the maxAMShare?